# Getting good online statistics of my socket.io clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

so i have a socket.io server with many socket.io clients connected to it and i am trying to get somewhat reliable online/offline statistics but i am not quite sure how to implement this as of right now i just added a "hearbeat" every 5 seconds on each client

just like this

```
setInterval(sendHeartbeat, 5000);

function sendHeartbeat(){
    socket.emit('heartbeat',pcName)
}
```

but i don't know how to handle this on the servers end to make sure that its getting heartbeats from each pc and after 10 seconds of it not it runs a function to say its offline

Comment: Isn't Socket, a continuous stable open connection? why do you need to send a heartbeat? Just listen the event connect/disconnect events

Comment: Yeah but if the user just straight up quits the client sometimes it won't send the disconnect event

Comment: Does that really happen?Weird. Even if the client doesn't send a disconnect, both ends will know if a disconnect occur because its a `TCP` connection.

Comment: yes i have tried using the `socket.on('disconnect', function(){});` and it wont work when i just exit the program